# Под Windows 10 форма не выводится поверх всех окон

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8

Есть программа на Delphi XE8, висящая в области уведомлений и при определённых событиях показывающая окно с информацией. Под Windows 7 следующий код обеспечивал показ формы поверх всех окон практически на 100%.

```
with TfrmInfo.Create(self) do
begin
  Show;
  Application.NormalizeTopMosts;
  SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    SWP_NOACTIVATE + SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE);
end;
```

И этот код перестал срабатывать под Windows 10. Точнее, иногда окно появляется поверх всех, но гораздо чаще оказывается наоборот в самом "низу", под всеми окнами. Может кто сталкивался с таким? И как это попробовать полечить?

Comment: Попробуйте советы с enSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772233/win32-setforegroundwindow-unreliable

Comment: _"практически на 100%"_ - это настораживает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Виновником" оказалась строка с Application.NormalizeTopMosts. Я её в своё время без особых раздумий по какому-то примеру в код вставил. И под семёркой она по крайней мере не мешала. А вот под десяткой получил проблему. Просто убрал эту строку - и всё заработало!

Comment: Примите свой ответ как верный. Нажмите галочку рядом с ответом.